# Show new activity message when page is visited using back button

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign

I get to see a message "1 question with new activity" when a question is posted newly. I click on that question and view it. Then I click on my browser back button. I don't see this newly posted question, but instead I get to see the previous visited page because this comes from browser cache and not from Server.

Now, I no more get to see "1 question with new activity" message if a question is posted newly. I have to either refresh the page using F5 OR click on Tags and again revisit to see the new questions under that tab.

Comment: What do you propose? This is normal, I think.

Comment: @qben When back button is clicked, I get to see previous visited page from cache is fine. But, atleast the ajax which shows,"1 question with new activity" should work. Else, whenever I visit a question, I am forced to press F5.

Comment: I've been wondering about this, too. I'd be open for some kind of userscript or other personal solution that would reload a question page automatically when navigating back to it.

Comment: @Juhana Agreed.. Now that this question is edited by adding the tag 'statuc-bydesign' I guess this would remain as it is. But just wondering why would anyone put this kind of a design..

Comment: The added banner is not part of the previous page - it wasn't there when it first loaded, so going back to that page wouldn't show it.

Comment: @Oded Much clear now. By any possibility can this be taken forward as a feature request?

Comment: @VikasV - Not sure how much effort this is, and if we want to put _any_ for very little gain. Consider that even with F5 you can lose the new questions (if they just missed the last cache window) and that we are not going to fix _that_.